# no entiendo la respuesta que obtengo en la terminal

Tags: git, github

en la terminal de VScode estoy colocando "git add -A" para guardar los cambios porque voy a subirlo a github, pero la respuesta que me da luego de ejecutarlo es "fatal: not a git repository (or any of the parent directories)"

sabrán porque me da esa respuesta?, tienen idea de que estaré haciendo mal?

Comment: ¿Es un repositorio de github nuevo que crearás tú o es repositorio que alguien ya creó?

Answer (score 4):

eso es porque no has inicializado el git en ese directorio... coloca primero `git init`
para inicializarlo, esto creará el directorio oculto .git